# What type of Schengen visa should I apply for a conference in Spain?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, spain

I'm a recent college graduate (unemployed) from Turkey and I plan to attend the [Cisco Live](https://www.ciscolive.com/global/about.html) conference in Barcelona. This is how the company organizing it defines the event:

> Cisco Live provides awe-inspiring experiences that fuel your personal and professional growth.
>
> Build the foundation for your digital future with Cisco Live, your destination for year-round technical content and events. Learn, explore, connect, and be inspired by Cisco’s top experts, partners, and customers. Cisco Live is the destination to immerse yourself in Cisco.

The conference is mainly visited by IT professionals to network, listen to keynotes and see some cool techie stuff. If I were one of them, I'd definitely go with the "business" category. However, I'm yet to become a professional and have only recently graduated. I don't aim to conduct business or make partners with this trip at all. My purpose for visiting Spain is a mixture of seeing some cool tech at the conference and learn from the experts there, and of course, travel around the city to see what Barcelona has to offer.

I think my purpose falls more under the "cultural" category, but I'm not clearly sure if this might sound misleading given how the conference itself is mainly for business people.

So, am I supposed to go with "Business"? "Cultural"? Or would it be better if I went with the "Other" and said something like "Technology Conference and Sightseeing"? Should I check "Tourism" box, too, since sightseeing is a part of my trip? I might as well be making this complicated for everyone, but as a new graduate with no job, I just want to make my intentions clear to the officials.

Comment: If Cisco issued an invitation letter with your name, you can check "Business". However, from what you're describing about your situation, I think the most appropriate is "Tourist" or/and "Cultural".

Comment: Having recently tried to justify a company trip to Mallorca, we needed to attend some kind of conference to justify it as business to the tax agency. This might not apply to visas however and I'd say that an IT conference is the same as attending a dance course or festival for someone interested in that. IT is something many has as hobbies.